# Is there a way to print the character / using the print function in python?

Tags: python, output, termux

I want to print some letters big in the terminal using / and some other characters but / has caused me some trouble.

when I tried to run it, the error "Syntax error: EOL while scanning string literal" popped up

```
print("/\")
print("\/")
print("\/")
print("/\")
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with print: `x = "\"` would be a syntax error as well, and `x = "\/"` would result in a string of one character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` shouldn't be a problem, but `\` definitely is, as it's the escape character, and `\"` (for example) allows you to display a `"`.

You have to use `\\` to display a single `\`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to escape `/`, just use `print("/")`

And if you want to print `\`, use `print("\\")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you expect as output, single backslashes need to be escaped:

```
print("/\\")
print("\\/")
print("\\/")
print("/\\")
```

Prints:

```
/\
\/
\/
/\
```

Answer (score 0):

Symbol '\' is an escape symbol after it you can give a symbol which could be interpreted in python in diferent way like \ " '. You see "Syntax error: EOL while scanning string literal" not because of '/' but because of '\' which escapes " and interpret it as a symbol then finds no string end.